# How to upload a file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I have this form where i ultimately want to be able to upload several files, and those files will appear in a textarea tag right underneath.  How do i upload files using javascript?

Comment: this might help you : [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

The easy path is go with a plugin. Here is an upload [plugin](http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload) for jQuery library.